# Check if directive attribute was passed

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Is there a way I can check if my Angular 1 directive was actually passed a declared but not initialized variable or if it wasn't passed the attribute I'm expecting?

Said with other words:

```
$scope.var;  // <-- declared but not initialized, value is "undefined"

<div my-directive foo-bar="var"></div>
```

How can I know from the `link` method in my directive that `foo-bar` actually had a variable passed? (instead of `<div my-directive></div>`)

Answer (score 0):

Use a watch in directive

```
app.directive('myDirective', function() {
  return {
    scope: {fooBar: '='},
    link: function(scope, elem, attrs) {
      scope.$watch('fooBar', function(newVal, oldVal) {
        if (newVal !== oldVal) {
          // we have a new scope value
        }
      });    
    }
  }    
});
```

Comment: This will tell me if the value of `var` changed, the problem is that `var` will be undefined (if passed) and won't change). So I must know if it was passed.

Comment: Will the variable be defined when controller runs or is it being set asynchronously in controller? What higher level problem are you trying to solve

Comment: Also are you just wanting to check if the attribute is empty or even exists?

Comment: The variable will be defined when the controllers runs, at the beginning. No higher problem. I must push a value to this variable from the directive, and I need to check if it exists (because if it doesn't, the moment I try to push a value to it, the code will break).

Comment: so why won't  watch do that for you? Or just check if it is defined before you run your code. Issue is not clear at all

Comment: I don't control the controller, my directive will be used by third parties. That's why I must check if my directive actually received an undefined variable (that exists in the controller) or if the directive didn't receive `foo-bar` (and if it didn't, don't try to push values to that variable).

Comment: so throw an error or console warning or something before you run code that would break

Comment: I want to avoid throwing errors, but to actually handle the error.

Comment: `try/catch` then. Not enough details given to help much more.

Comment: What more details do you need? I already told you the entire scenario. Try/catching my entire code is not a proper solution but a monkey-patch.

Comment: then just return when variable is undefined and log a warning in console or do something in UI. Really not sure what you are looking for other than that

Comment: I already told you that the expected usage is to pass an `undefined`, but declared variable. The problem is that not passing a variable at all also creates an `undefined` value. Those things might sound like they are the same, but they are not. Trying to assign something in the first case will work without problem, while doing so in the second case will produce an `assigning value to undefined` error.

Comment: create some sort of demo to help understand the issue

Comment: https://plnkr.co/edit/x8gpNiqKTVcGQNDk7BkL?p=preview Here you go. To reproduce the bug I'm talking about, remove the `foo-bar="name"` from the `index.html` file.

Comment: OK... this isn't pretty but it works. It sets the scope using it's own watch in `pre link `. Not sure if this will work for you or not https://plnkr.co/edit/eYdSztGhDzwtfWzYcRlC?p=preview

Comment: This doesn't work. I can pass `foo-bar="non-existing-var"` and it says that `fooBar` is created by the attribute.

Comment: So that means none of it is any good and you can't modify it to check for that condition yourself?

Comment: Exactly, I don't own the controller (my directive will be used by third-parties and I don't control what the controller's code will look like)

Comment: But I'm asking if you even tried? That condition should be easy enough to check

Comment: Yes, I tried. The problem is in passing non-existing variables. I'm not sure if there is a way to check whether a variable es declared (but not defined) in the parent scope of the directive.

Comment: Note that doing `$scope.something;` in the parent scope and then trying to find `something` from the directive with `$scope.$parent` won't be possible as `something` won't appear (but it is declared).

Comment: Did you try adding `attrs.$observe()` for that condition? If you want more help then fork demo with all the test cases and expected results

Comment: That won't help either. I don't expect the variable to change it's value from the controller, so I'll get `undefined` from `$observe`, which doesn't tell me if it's defined but not declared or if it doesn't exist.

Comment: Well I don't know anything about your directive, what it does or why it is so important that if values aren't provided you can't put warnings in UI, or write unit tests for other developers. So far I've done all the work here and not going to continue if you don't put some effort into forking demo and putting more effort in